# 400 bad request error when sending hits with Firefox user-agent to GA Measurement Protocol

Tags: firefox, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm sending hits to GA Measurement Protocol, and some of them do not make it to the GA. I've noticed that all of them have one thing in common: the user-agent is Firefox, only varying version and device. Some examples:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0
- Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0
- Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0
- Mozilla/5.0 (Android 10; Mobile; rv:103.0) Gecko/103.0 Firefox/103.0

GA validator is OK with those examples when checking them through the debug mode like this:

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-1&t=event&ec=Ecommerce&ea=purchase&pa=purchase&cid=1234567890.1234567890&ni=1&ti=184242&tr=1060&uip=X.X.X.X&ua=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%3B+rv%3A103.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F103.0&pr1id=test_1&pr1pr=530&pr1qt=1&pr1ps=1
```

I get this response:

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1..."
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

BUT in the production settings GA responses with **400 bad request** error to the same requests without providing any details: *"Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know."*.

So what might be wrong with Firefox UA?

UPD: I've managed to make this work by unsetting the 'User-Agent' header in case it contains 'Firefox' - and the corresponding 'ua' parameter in the payload gets accepted then.

```
if (strpos($requestHeaders['User-Agent'], 'Firefox') !== false) {
    unset($requestHeaders['User-Agent']);
}
```

But it's still unclear what was wrong with such headers in the first place.